# What are dompdf_img_* files?

Tags: linux, cpanel

I noticed recently that my tmp directory is starting to fill up and it seems that it is filling up with file that start with dompdf_img_*.  Whatever program that is creating these files is not cleaning them up or not cleaning them up as often as I would like.  Does anyone know what program creates these files and if there is a way regulate how long they are kept on the server?

Using CENTOS 6.2 x86_64 and WHM 11.30.6

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be related to the [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) library. Since you seem unaware it's even on your site, it's probably being used as a library by some utility or plugin for a CMS, for example. Does your site offer a feature to download a given page as a PDF? That would be the first place to look.

Answer (score 2):

[Dompdf](http://twitter.com/#!/dompdf) is a html to PDF converter, it has a PHP rendering engine and reads in external style sheets.

The project lives at http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ I'm sure they have a support channel that might be able to help get the cleanup correct.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what part of your site generates PDF files, as they said in other answers it's part of the Dompdf php library.

You could use a shell script to clear your tmp folder and set a cron job to run as often as you'd like

```
#!/bin/bash 
rm -rf /tmp/* 
rm -rf/var/tmp/* 
fsck -A
exit
```